# The event show in continuous date

Tags: javascript, angular, lumen

I tried to get the event from API but here what happen.]
Here's my code for getting that event in my Angular project

```
this.calendarOptions = {
 height: 'parent',
 fixedWeekCount : false,
 defaultDate: '2017-05-01',
 editable: true,
 eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
 events : function(start, end, timezone, callback) {
  $.ajax({
   url: 'http://localhost:8000/api/event/show',
   dataType: 'json',
   data: {
     // our hypothetical feed requires UNIX timestamps
     start: start.unix(),
     end: end.unix()
   },
   success: function(data) {
     var events = data;
     callback(events);
   }
 });
}
```

**This is my Query for getting those event from databse**
*this is the model*

```
public static function eventLists($start_date, $end_date){
    return DB::table('event')
            ->select(DB::raw('name as title'), 
                     DB::raw('DATE(start_time) as start'), 
                     DB::raw('DATE(end_time) as end'))
            ->whereBetween(DB:raw($start_date, $end_date))
            ->get();

}
```

*This is my Controller*

```
> public function showEvent(Request $request){

    /**
    * get query string
    * get array data [start, end]
    */
    $queryString = $request->all();

    $start_date = date("Y-m-d",$queryString['start']);
    $end_date = date("Y-m-d",$queryString['end']);

    $data = EventModel::eventLists($start_date, $end_date);
    $data = $data;
    // $data = [ 'data' => $data ];

    return response()->json($data)->withHeaders([
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' => '*', 
      'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' => 'X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Origin, Authorization',
      'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' => 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS'
    ]);

}
```

Comment: What's the issue exactly ?

Comment: the problem is the event in showing in contionous date. The event should show on the date given. this is the example data from my DB

Comment: @theZaki [{title: "aly day", start: "2017-04-01", end: "2017-04-06"},…]
0
:
{title: "aly day", start: "2017-04-01", end: "2017-04-06"}
1
:
{title: "team lunch ", start: "2017-04-05", end: "2017-04-06"}
2
:
{title: "team buliding", start: "2017-04-01", end: "2017-04-01"}
3
:
{title: "test", start: "2017-04-05", end: "2017-04-06"}
4
:
{title: "jen day", start: "2017-01-19", end: "2017-05-01"}

Comment: The query has to `SELECT` name, start, end `FROM` event `WHERE`  start_time `BETWEEN` ($start_date, $end_date)

Comment: @bluehipy yah I tried to do that Im but I'm having an issue with my query. It gives me an error with this ->whereBetween((DB:raw($start_date, $end_date))

Comment: Show the query. I don't get what are you using for the db abstractization but should be fairly easy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static function eventLists($start_date, $end_date){
return DB::table('event')
        ->select(DB::raw('name as title'), 
                 DB::raw('DATE(start_time) as start'), 
                 DB::raw('DATE(end_time) as end'))
        ->whereBetween('start', array($start_date, $end_date))
        ->get();

 }
```

Comment: now its working. Thanks for your help. have a good one :))))))

Comment: Good luck with your project ;)